# occur node uncheck - treeview

Tags: c#, winforms

Is there an event fires when the user unchecks a node in Treeview?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the [TreeView.AfterCheck](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.aftercheck.aspx) event.

Comment: you are right! thanks!
when I read the description of the function I thought it just fires after checking...
thanks again!!!

Comment: No problem, my pleasure Moshe.